# JS: search for specific string in textarea

Tags: javascript, string, textarea, project

I am working on a project for an intro course on JavaScript and I really need help on one aspect.

How would I search for a string within a block of text in a play?
For example how could I search for Messenger in the text below and use it as a value?

Rather than have a whole BLOCK of text like below it should look more like this format:

`AGAMEMNON: //dialogue`
`CLYTAEMNESTRA: //dialogue`
AGAMEMNON //dialogue

So far I have tried the .match property and the .indexOf property but don't know what my other options are.

Please help!

> CLYTAEMNESTRA
>         Don’t say that just to flout what I’ve arranged.
>   AGAMEMNON
>         You should know I’ll not go back on what I’ve said.
>   CLYTAEMNESTRA
>         You must fear something, then, to act this way.
>         You’ve made some promise to the gods.                                1100
>   AGAMEMNON
>         I’ve said my final word. I fully understand,
>         as well as any man, just what I’m doing.
>   CLYTAEMNESTRA
>         What do you think Priam would have done,
>         if he’d had your success?
>   AGAMEMNON
>         That’s clear—
>         he’d have walked across these tapestries.
>   CLYTAEMNESTRA
>         So then why be ashamed by what men say?
>   AGAMEMNON
>         But what people say can have great power.
>   CLYTAEMNESTRA
>         True, but the man whom people do not envy
>         is not worth their envy.

Comment: What is your expected result from this text sample?

Comment: Ideally 
1. it would work similar to a find function on a browser and find the name of one of the "speakers." 
2. I could find a way to take the dialogue they say after as a separate string.

Comment: Just include the expected result in your question. This will make it easier to have good answers.

Comment: you have to get the `textarea`'s value, something like this: `document.getElementById("textareaID").value`, and then you can use `.indexOf` to search the text

Comment: @Tresdin I made some edits, to my question. Does that sound more clear?

mjr - I tried this but it only gives me the position of it.
        inputText = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
        match1 = inputText.indexOf(char1Name);
        document.body.innerHTML = match1;

Comment: Oh. I see you've changed the example...

Comment: Fixed answer to account for changed example.

Answer (score 1):

1) Get the text content of the textarea

```
var txt = document.querySelector('textarea').textContent;
```

2) Define the regex to split the areas of the text into component parts

```
var regex = /[A-Z]+ [\w’, ]+\./g
```

3) Return an array of matches

```
var roles = txt.match(regex);
```

4) `map` over the array and return an array of HTML of names and descriptions

```
var html = roles.map(function (role) {
  role = role.replace(/([A-Z]+) /, '$1:').split(':');
  return [
    '<div class="name">',
    role[0],
    '</div>',
    '<div class="desc">',
    role[1],
    '</div>'].join('');
});
```

5) Add the HTML to the DOM

```
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = html.join('');
```

OUTPUT

> **CLYTAEMNESTRA**
>
> Don’t say that just to flout what I’ve arranged.
>
> **AGAMEMNON**
>
> You should know I’ll not go back on what I’ve said.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jhrg6re2/2/)